# STM32 read external FIFO through FSMC

Tags: stm32

I want to use FSMC of STM32F429 to read external FIFO implemented in an FPGA MAX10. Since no mode of FSMC can fit the FIFO interface precisely, I try to use the modified synchronous multiplexed PSRAM mode.

My plan is like this

**A[25:16]**: Ignored, don't connect to FIFO;

**NEx, NOE, NADV**: Implement a simple logic in FPGA that when NEx is valid and the NADV is data valid, connect the inverted NOE to the RD port of FIFO;

**NWE**: ignored, only read operation is needed;

**D[15:0]**: Connect to the output data port of FIFO;

There may be also some logic in FPGA to adjust the timing between NOE and D[15:0], but that is not a big problem.

My questions are:

1. Is this plan feasible? Is there any problem with this plan?
2. How can I extend the reading burst as long as possible? Since there are 2048x16bit in one frame, ideally, I want to read them all in one burst if possible.

Updated:

I've implemented the design which read FPGA FIFO through the FSMC interface in sync PSRAM Non-multiplexed mode successfully. Currently, each burst can only transmit 2x16bit data but it's already fast enough for my project.

[image]